# Find all indices of a search term in a string

Tags: string, swift

I need a fast method to find all indices of a search term that might occur in a string. I tried this 'brute force' `String` extension method:

```
// Note: makes use of ExSwift
extension String
{
    var length: Int { return count(self) }

    func indicesOf(searchTerm:String) -> [Int] {
        var indices = [Int]()
        for i in 0 ..< self.length {
            let segment = self[i ... (i + searchTerm.length - 1)]
            if (segment == searchTerm) {
                indices.append(i)
            }
        }
        return indices;
    }
}
```

... But it's ridiculously slow, especially the shorter the search term is. What would be a better method to find all indices fast?

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using? Your code does not compile in Xcode 6.3.2 or Xcode 7 beta.

Comment: Xcode 6.3.2. Maybe you're missing String.length? `var length: Int { return count(self) }`

Comment: String does not have a property length in my Xcode 6.3.2 (and also you cannot subscript strings with integers). Perhaps you are using some extensions?

Comment: Oh right, the subscripting ... I use ExSwift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking for the search term at each position of the string
you could use `rangeOfString()` to find the next occurrence (hoping
that `rangeOfString()` uses more advanced algorithms):

```
extension String {

    func indicesOf(searchTerm:String) -> [Int] {
        var indices = [Int]()
        var pos = self.startIndex
        while let range = self.rangeOfString(searchTerm, range: pos ..< self.endIndex) {
            indices.append(distance(self.startIndex, range.startIndex))
            pos = range.startIndex.successor()
        }
        return indices
    }
}
```

Generally, it depends on the size of the input string and the size
of the search string which algorithm is "the fastest". You'll find
an overview with links to various algorithms in
[String searching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
extension String {

    func indices(of searchTerm:String) -> [Int] {
        var indices = [Int]()
        var pos = self.startIndex
        while let range = range(of: searchTerm, range: pos ..< self.endIndex) {
            indices.append(distance(from: startIndex, to: range.lowerBound))
            pos = index(after: range.lowerBound)
        }
        return indices
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method is a lot faster, the text I'm testing it on has 1000 to 2000 characters. Thanks for this solution. I can put the regexp experiments back into the drawer again.

Comment: @Martin R Instead of indices.append(distance(from: startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)) can it be that arrayOfIndices.append(range.lowerBound.encodedOffset) is faster ?

Comment: @VYT: That might be, but it gives different results. Try `"!".indices(of: "!")`

Comment: @Martin R Yes, for emojis it is not good. (I am not using code for string with emojis).

Answer (score 5):

As Martin said you can implement some of the well known fastest algorithms in String Matching, The [Knuth–Morris–Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) string searching algorithm (or **KMP** algorithm) searches for occurrences of a "word" `W` within a main "text string" `S`.

The algorithm has complexity [O(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time), where *n* is the length of `S` and the *O* is [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big-O_notation).

```
extension String {

    // Build pi function of prefixes
    private func build_pi(str: String) -> [Int] {

       var n = count(str)
       var pi = Array(count: n + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
       var k = -1
       pi[0] = -1

       for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
           while (k >= 0 && str[k] != str[i]) {
              k = pi[k]
           }
           pi[i + 1] = ++k
       }

       return pi
    }

    // Knuth-Morris Pratt algorithm
    func searchPattern(pattern: String) -> [Int] {

       var matches = [Int]()
       var n = count(self)

       var m = count(pattern)
       var k = 0
       var pi = build_pi(pattern)

       for var i = 0; i < n; ++i {
           while (k >= 0 && (k == m || pattern[k] != self[i])) {
              k = pi[k]
           }
           if ++k == m {
              matches.append(i - m + 1)
           }
       }

       return matches
    }

    subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
        return self[advance(self.startIndex, i)]
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in the following way:

```
var string = "apurba mandal loves ayoshi loves"
var pattern = "loves"

println(string.searchPattern(pattern))
```

An the output should be :

```
[14, 27]
```

That belong to the start index of the pattern occurrences inside the the string. I hope this help you.

> **EDIT:**

As Martin said in his comment you need to avoid the use of the `advance` function to index an `String` by an `Int` because it's *O(position to index)*.

One possible solution is to convert the `String` to an array of `Character` and then access to the indexes is *O(1)*.

Then the `extension` can be changed to this one :

```
extension String {

   // Build pi function of prefixes
   private func build_pi(str: [Character]) -> [Int] {

      var n = count(str)
      var pi = Array(count: n + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
      var k = -1
      pi[0] = -1

      for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          while (k >= 0 && str[k] != str[i]) {
              k = pi[k]
          }
          pi[i + 1] = ++k
      }

      return pi
   }

   // Knuth-Morris Pratt algorithm
   func searchPattern(pattern: String) -> [Int] {

      // Convert to Character array to index in O(1)
      var patt = Array(pattern)
      var S = Array(self)

      var matches = [Int]()
      var n = count(self)

      var m = count(pattern)
      var k = 0
      var pi = build_pi(patt)

      for var i = 0; i < n; ++i {
         while (k >= 0 && (k == m || patt[k] != S[i])) {
             k = pi[k]
         }
         if ++k == m {
             matches.append(i - m + 1)
         }
      }

      return matches
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that `advance(self.startIndex, i)` for *strings* executes in O(i), so that must also be taken into account. It might be better to work with `String.Index` instead of `Int` indices, if possible.

Comment: Yes you're right @MartinR I would update my answer. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: I made some simple performance test, and your updated code is about a factor 250 faster than the original version. Whether it is slower or faster than my (simple rangeOfString-based) method seems to depend on the search string and how often it occurs. Generally, your method is faster for shorter strings which occur more frequently. I assume that rangeOfString internally also uses some sophisticated search method.

Comment: It could be very interesting know exactly what algorithm use `rangeOfString` , I tried to find out, but not luck so far. The Knuth-Morris-Pratt (KMP) algorithm is a good choice if we want to search for the same pattern repeatedly in many different texts.

Comment: Great suggestions here! Thanks for the code examples! For now Martin's method works fast enough for my purpose but I might add the KMP search to my lib for later.

Answer (score 1):

Using NSRegularExpression in Swift 4, you can do it like this. `NSRegularExpression` has been around forever and is probably a better choice than rolling your own algorithm for most cases.

```
let text = "The quieter you become, the more you can hear."
let searchTerm = "you"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchTerm, options: [])
let range: NSRange = NSRange(text.startIndex ..< text.endIndex, in: text)
let matches: [NSTextCheckingResult] = regex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: range)
let ranges: [NSRange] = matches.map { $0.range }
let indices: [Int] = ranges.map { $0.location }
let swiftRanges = ranges.map { Range($0, in: text) }
let swiftIndices: [String.Index] = swiftRanges.flatMap { $0?.lowerBound }
```