# Character in String array swift

Tags: swift, string, character, indexof, for-in-loop

I'm trying to find the position of the letters that make up a string. 
For example, I need to know the positions of the letter "c" in the word "character" for further calculation.

I tried

```
for letters in Array("character".characters) {
    if "c".contains(String(letters)) {
    if let i = Array("character".characters).index(of: letters) {
    print(i) 
    }
   } else { print("wrong letter") }
  }

// Console:
0
wrong letter
wrong letter
wrong letter
wrong letter
0
wrong letter
wrong letter
wrong letter
```

All I get from the console are two zeros; it's only giving me the index of the first c in "character" but not the second c. 
The fact that it prints out "wrong letter" means the loop is running correctly; it even recognise the position of the second c, it's just not giving the correct index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work as intended because

```
Array("character".characters).index(of: letters)
```

always finds the *first* occurrence of the letter in the string, e.g.
when searching for "c" this will always return the index zero.

You can simplify the task by using `enumerated()`,
which gives you the characters together with the corresponding index,
and makes all `Array()` conversions and searching via `index(of:)` unnecessary:

```
let word = "character"
let search = Character("c")

for (index, letter) in word.characters.enumerated() where letter == search {
    print(index)
}
// 0  5
```

Or, if you want the indices as an array:

```
let indices = word.characters.enumerated()
    .filter { $0.element == search }
    .map { $0.offset }


print(indices) // [0, 5]
```

This can be further optimized to

```
let indices = word.characters.enumerated()
    .flatMap { $0.element == search ? $0.offset : nil }
```

If the string is *large* then other methods might be better suited,
see e.g. [Find all indices of a search term in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890920/find-all-indices-of-a-search-term-in-a-string).

Answer (score 0):

You can do as

```
let test  = "character"
let arr = Array(test.characters)
for i in 0..<arr.count {
if arr[i] == "c"{

    print(i)
    } else { print("wrong letter") }

}
output
// 0
//wrong letter
//wrong letter
//wrong letter
//wrong letter
//5
//wrong letter
//wrong letter
//wrong letter
```